# How to get the value of item POST in JForm after submit?

Tags: php, xml, joomla

I am currently constructing a component in Joomla and I have to get the values of the form field that user submitted. After that, I have to insert the values into database. The problem is that I just able to insert the `$inventory_id` but I can't get the value of the form field. Thank you.

```
<?php
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; 
    $formData = new JRegistry($input->get('jform', '', 'array')); 

    $name = $formData->get('inventory_name', 'test');
    $leadtime = $formData->get('leadtime', null);
    $max_lead = $formData->get('max_lead', null);
    $daily_usage = $formData->get('daily_usage', null);
    $max_usage = $formData->get('max_usage', null); 

    //formula to calculate reorder point
    $lead_time_demand = $leadtime * $daily_usage;
    $safety_stock = ($max_usage * $max_lead) - ($daily_usage * $leadtime);
    $reorder_point = $lead_time_demand + $safety_stock;

    if (empty($this->item->id)){ //For new added item
        $inventory_id = $row['AUTO_INCREMENT'];

        $sql_new = "INSERT INTO wer_reorder_point_list (inventory_id, inventory_name, reorder_point)
                    VALUES ('$inventory_id', '$name', '$reorder_point');";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql_new);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should use the Joomla api to make the query.

Answer (score 1):

You never declare `$row` in this code, so what is `$inventory_id = $row['AUTO_INCREMENT'];` supposed to do?

If your database is configured to autoincrement `inventory_id`, then you don't need that column in the insert statement. So you could do this:

```
$sql_new = "INSERT INTO wer_reorder_point_list (inventory_name, reorder_point) 
VALUES ('$name', '$reorder_point');";
```

and it will automatically fill that column with the next integer.

By the way, you should also use [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), especially since you have user input, which could be a security problem.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention about the `$row` declaration in the question. I have declared it in my code in other lines. The only problem is that I cannot get the value from the form field.

Comment: Ah, so the values of `$name` etc. are not inserting as expected. I am not familiar with this library, but perhaps you could try `var_dump()` on your variables, before trying to insert them? Maybe the problem is with the `$formData` object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't insert an autoincremented id directly using the form data, you let the database take care of that. If you tried to insert it you could easily end up with a race condition given that in a web application such as Joomla there could be many users attempting to insert new lines with the same id at the same time.  This is why your form does not contain an inventory_id value.
If you want to pass a hidden ( from the user) value to the POST you need to include a hidden field with that value in your form. However, as stated in the first paragraph, you would not use that for a unique ID.